# What's could class "Oscar" possibly be doing there?

Tags: c++

In this line?

```
std::unique_ptr<Lucille<Oscar>> mBuster;
```

If it's either one of Lucille or Oscar then I have no problem understanding that it's for creating an *empty* pointer to either class types. But there are two. What's going on?

Comment: You might need to provide a little more detail.

Comment: The code looks incomplete, where the other half the `>`?

Comment: `Lucille` is a template type. So? Do you know much about C++?

Comment: Not at all, apparently.

Comment: @tron `>` are for quotes. For code snippets just indent the text by 4 spaces. If you need more help with formatting, we also have a [formatting help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: And stackoverflow keep auto-parsing my content thus the incomplete code. Frustrating. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @TronVolta do you know how templates work in C++? Otherwise the answers probably need some more explanations.

Comment: Tried 4 spaces thing. Worked like the 3 seashells, which is why I switched to "quote" thingy in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Cap'n. I shoulda known reading a book backwards is a bad idea.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl No not really, crash-coursing in 5, 4,3,...

Answer (score 2):

This declares a `std::unique_ptr` to an instance of a template class `Lucille`, with `Oscar` as its template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::unique_ptr<Lucille<Oscar>> mBuster;
```

It's creating a `unique_ptr` `Lucille` of type `Oscar`.

Much like: `std::vector<queue<stack>>`, which is a vector of queues containing stacks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem simply seems to be that you aren't familiar with the concept of templates in C++ yet.

It's somewhat similar to function parameters. The function

```
foo(int value);
```

takes a value of type int as parameter, you can pass any int value. Templates make this a bit different, they aren't used to pass values, they are used to pass types as arguments.

To use a little bit of a simpler example let's look at `vector`:

```
std::vector<int> ivector; // works on int values
ivector.push_back(5);

std::vector<std::string> strvector; // works on string values
strvector.push_back("Hello");
```

the part within the angular brackets `<>` are the template parameters. You can see that we can simply pass some type and all the functions will work for that specific type.

Now `unique_ptr<type>` takes the type to point to as a template argument. Your `std::unique_ptr<Lucille<Oscar>>` points to a value of type `Lucille<Oscar>`. Lucille is itself a template and works on values of type `Oscar`.

Comment: Thank you Miedl, I regret having but one upvote to give.